# Java/Android will not allow "this" as parameter in Intent declaration

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am defining an Intent inside of a protected function inside a private class. I am brand new to Java/Android and do not know how I pass the parameter to Intent. I have been using "this" in other Activities but I am getting a complaint from AndroidStudio.

```
Intent setSession = new Intent(this, posterSessionSetup.class);
```

> Cannot resolve constructor Intent(.....

```
 private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            //get the text input and validate it
            EditText userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
            EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passWord);

            return readJSONFeed("mywebservice", userName.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject r = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("r"));
                String status = r.getString("status");
                String msg = r.getString("msg");
                if (status == "complete"){
    --------->>>>>> Intent setSession = new Intent(this, posterSessionSetup.class);
                    startActivity(setSession);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), r.getString("status") + ":" + r.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Read Json File", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Not that it is related to your problem but `if (status == "complete"){` doesn't look good. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: use status.contentEquals("complete")

Comment: That is my javaScript/PHP background showing. I will read up on contentEquals. Thank you~!

Comment: @Pshemo @ CQM.. You were right. It did not compare properly until I changed it to ContentEquals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in [the inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) `AsyncCaller`  so `this` refers to that class. You can use e.g. `YourActivityClass.this` if the outer class is named `YourActivityClass` to reference the outer class

Comment: so the main class is Public Login extends android.app.Activity{}.. I would use Login.class or Login.this?

Comment: Login.this if your class is public class Login

Answer (score 1):

This refers there to the asynctask inatance.

Uae the activity or whatever that class is embeded in.

Comment: Which, for example, can be accessed via `MainActivity.this`. Although that's not exactly pretty.